# ranking data in excel without skipping values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i found this formula : `=COUNTIF(D$2:D$60000,">"&D2)+1`  that gives me ranking of some data but it skips values like in the picture 
[image]
is there any solution to solve this problem like to have a normal ranking without skiping values , thanks

Comment: Which column is column D.  with your screen shot you cut off the column identifiers.

Comment: the column D is where i have numbers wait i will update the picture

Comment: What scott has presented below is that all ties, or duplicate entries get the same value and then the next group or unique item gets the next number and so on.   What you had in your example before was duplicates all got the same number, but the next item or group would get the next number as if all items in the duplicate group had go individual numbers.  If scotts answer below does not work for you and your previous formula is not working for you, can you please provide an example showing the numbering you would like to see.

Comment: @ForwardEd i will update the picture with the result that i hope i get

Comment: Mateos that look like what scott gave you.  he mixed up the number you were counting to show the formula would work even if your numbers were not grouped.

Comment: yes i tried the formula but the results are just zeros  in all the column

Comment: are you pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER when you finish placing the formula in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

This array formula will do it:

```
=SUM(IF((D$2:D$60000>D30)*(D$2:D$60000<>""),(1/(COUNTIF(D$2:D$60000,D$2:D$60000)))*(D$2:D$60000>D30)))+1
```

Being an array formula it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: AhHH took me a while to figure this out...so basically he does not want the Olympic medal system for ties!  yeah clear as mud that statement of mine.

Comment: @ForwardEd I got your meaning.

Comment: @ScottCraner i entred the formula as it should but the results is just zeros

Comment: @mateos did you enter it with the button combination Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of only Enter)?

Comment: yes  i did what you told me to do and also excel added those brackets but the result is zero in all the column down !

Comment: @matros into which cell did you put the formula to start?

Comment: into Cell 2 the data that i want to rank start from A2

Comment: Did you change all the cell references to the correct column and cell?